# I would like to write a syntax highlighting editor extension for VS 2019 in C++ (nothing else), are there any samples to get me started?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, sample

I would like to write a syntax highlighting editor extension for VS 2019 in C++ (nothing else), are there any samples to get me started?

I can only find one example extension for VS 2019 written in C++ and it consists of a subclass with no explanations of how to do anything AFAI can see.

I believe I need a language editor extension, but am not 100%

The language it needs to highlight is similar to assembler.

If this was VS6, I might have just used the custom keyword colouriser.

Comment: I wonder why you want to create such extension with c++. And VS SDK interfaces are more suitable for c#. Besides, you can  try to refer to [this link](https://github.com/Art-Stea1th/Enhanced-Syntax-Highlighting) and hope it could help you.

Comment: Because I can't stand C#. My preferred languages are asm (8bit), C, C++ and occasionally (although not for a long time) ML. I understand that VS has gone very C# (and in my opinion has suffered greatly performance wise from it), but as I am doing this for fun, I don't want to take the fun out of it. I will have a better look at that plugin, but still think that minimal C/C++ examples are great things to have.

Comment: I think you should check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019).In VS IDE, it has a extension project template and with c#, you will develop such extension more easily.

Comment: Thanks, I have been through those documents and I'm sure that they will help as long as the C++ API is similar enough.

Comment: Be glad to know that these documents do help for you.Actually, for VS IDE, you should use [VSIX Project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-the-vsix-project-template?view=vs-2019) to start your project.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to write a syntax highlighting editor extension for VS
>   2019 in C++ (nothing else), are there any samples to get me started?

**In current VS IDE, Microsoft does not advocate writing extensions in c++.**

As **Microsoft** recommends, current extensions are more likely to use `c#` rather than `c++`.

[image]

**Although** some VS SDK APIs are probably written in `c++`, but the interfaces are still called using `c#`.

**However**, there is only one c++ project template called [vspakcage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/loading-vspackages?view=vs-2019)

[image]

But this project provides various background services for VS IDE . It will only be loaded when needed. So for you to add the syntax highlighting feature permanently, this project is afraid of lacking.

**Besides**, there is no official documentation to guide the writing of the c++ project.

**Suggestion**

You can try to write such extension in c#, and you can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019) and [this](https://github.com/Art-Stea1th/Enhanced-Syntax-Highlighting).

**In addition**, if you still want your feature, I suggest you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).(click **suggest a feature**). Then you can share the link with us here and anyone who is interested in this feature will vote for you so that it will get **Microsoft's** attention.